# python - requests.get with HTTPBasicAuth works with text, not with var's

Tags: python, python-requests, anaconda

I try to get some xml-files from a website via requests.get
This works perfectly as long as I pass username and password via string, but not when I try to pass them via vars received by using get_password.

I have double checked every part by slowly replacing every bit in requests.get and it all goes wrong as soon as i use a var for the username or password part (or combined for that part). It seems that none of the 2 are being send along with my request.

The error I get is that tree has no content to parse (basically the site refused my request).

To make it clear: the code does work if I don't use the variables part in requests.get.

Os used is windows 10 along with Anaconda 4.3 framework (python 3.6). (note:I have removed the url/username in the codesnippet, but the site uses HTTPBasicAuth for sure :))I'm getting the very sneaky feeling that it's some kind of obvious thing I'm missing or a bug that needs squashing.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from keyring import set_password
from keyring import get_password

a = '<url>'

username = '<workingusernameforsite>'
set_password('sn', username, '<verysecretpassword')
wachtwoord = str(get_password('sn', username))

page = requests.get(a, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, wachtwoord))
tree = ET.fromstring(page.content)

for element in tree.findall(".//number"):
    print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is fixed. It seems anaconda messed up some references to the package, stating that it was installed and available, but actually being unable to install it correctly.

I tried reproducing it on another machine, which gave me a somewhat different error that the keyring package wasn't available. After trying to reinstall anaconda freshly, and trying to install the keyring package via conda, it gave me a weird permissions error.

I then installed keyring via pip, which now lets my script run flawlessly. I have no clue what caused the error or the weird messup, but possibly it's a bug in unmet dependencies in conda/anaconda. Will try to reproduce it once more on a tidy virtual machine and report a bug to anaconda if it turns out to be an issue beside a stupid user ;)